# Module output broken by full site cache

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, full-page-cache

I have a module that converts page information (product, basket, transaction) from their blocks to javascript objects.

We are having some issues using it on sites that have full site cache enabled. Things like users email addresses being cached and showing for other people. Obviously bad,

Is there a way to punch through the cache for an entire module (i.e if the module asks for the product information block, it won't get a cached version of it?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126548/trying-get-dynamic-content-hole-punched-through-magentos-full-page-cache